# Using 'foreach' to run on all possible permutations in R

Tags: r, foreach, linear-regression, parallel.foreach

I am having trouble understanding how to make my code parallel. My desire is to find 3 vectors out of a matrix of 20 that produce the closest linear regression to my measured variable (which means that there are a total of 1140 different combinations). Currently, I was able to use 3 nested    `foreach`    loops that return the best vectors. However, my desire is to make the outer loop (or all of them?) work in parallel. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
NIR= matrix(rexp(100, rate=0.01),ncol=20, nrow = 4) #Creating the matrix with 20 vectors
colnames(NIR)=c(1:20)

S.measured=c(7,9,11,13) #Measured variable

bestvectors<-matrix(data=NA,ncol = 3+1, nrow= 1) #creating a vector to save in it the best results 

###### Parallel stuff
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#nested foreach loop to exhaustively find the best vectors
foreach(i=1:numcols) %:% 
  foreach(j=i:numcols) %:% 
    foreach(k=j:numcols) %do% {
      if(i==j|i==k|j==k){ #To prevent same vector from being used twice 
      }
      else{
        lm<-lm(S.measured~NIR[,c(i,j,k)]-1) # package that calculates the linear regression 
        S.pred<-as.matrix(lm$fitted.values) # predicted vector to be compared with the actual measured one
        error<-sqrt(sum(((S.pred-S.measured)/S.measured)^2)) # The 'Error' which is the product of the comparison which we want to minimize 


#if the error is smaller than the last best one, it replaces it. If not nothing changes

if(error<as.numeric(bestvectors[1,3+1])|is.na(bestvectors[1,3+1])){
          bestvectors[1,]<-c(colnames(NIR)[i],colnames(NIR)[j],colnames(NIR)[k],as.numeric(error))
          bestvectors[,3+1]<-as.numeric(bestvectors[,3+1])
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably simplest to enumerate the 1140 combos and then parallelise on that rather than working with multiple nested loops. (I haven't used `foreach` and so don't have a full answer.)

Comment: The example I am using is a simple one. In reality I am looking for the best 5 vectors out of 150 which ends up being 591,600,030 combinations. I don't think that enumerating all of the combos would be practical.

Comment: Maybe it's more `stats.stackexchange.com` than R programming related then. There are methods to deal with combinatorial explosion like stepwise selection

Comment: Exhaustive search variable selection is impractical for a set this big. The `leaps` package makes forwards/backwards selection simple, or just use the lasso. Reading: [Chapter 6 of the venerable _ISLR_](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately forward and backward selection doesn't necessarily give me the best results. I am aware that exhaustive searching isn't the most practical approach, but still I am interested in applying it to my research. `leaps` package also has exhaustive calculation, but I believe that there isn't a difference between their method than mine. What I would like to do is have my outer loop work in parallel, meaning that in this case if I had 20 processors working simultaneously the amount of time it would take would be equivalent to 2 `for` loops and not 3. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General advice for using `foreach`:

1. Use `foreach(i=1:numcols) %dopar% { ... }` if you would like your code to run on multiple cores. The `%do%` decorator imperfectly simulates parallelism but runs on a single core.
2. Processes spawned by `%dopar%` cannot communicate with each other while the loop is running. So, set up your code to output an R object, like a `data.frame` or `vector`, then do comparison afterwards. In your case, the logic in the `if(error<as.numeric ...` line should be executed sequentially (not in parallel) after your main `foreach` loop.
3. Behavior of nested `%dopar%` loops is inconsistent across operating systems and is unclear in the way it spawns processes across cores. For best performance and portability, use a single `foreach` loop in the outermost loop and then vanilla `for` loops within it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to create 3 nested `foreach` loops in the end, with the two inner ones using the `%do%` decorator and the outer using `%dopar%`. Now my problem is the logical statement `if(error<as.numeric ...`. I don't want to have to sort my `data.frame` , especially not in the case of having 600 million object in it. I tried writing a `.combine` function as follows: `mycomb <- function(x,y) if(x$error<y$error) x else y` but it only works on the outer `foreach` loop and it doesn't give me the result I was expecting.

Comment: You'll have a better time using the ".combine=" parameter if your inner loops use `for(...){...}` instead of `foreach(...)%do%{...}`.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to parallelize that process of find the minimum error in the same fashion. If your institution has access to distributed computing, look into an R distribution that auto-parallelizes apply-style functions on clusters.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I ended up using 3 `foreach` loops where the outer one uses `%dopar%` and the two inner ones use `%do%`. As for sorting, I will try and sort the `data.frame` only after it is produced, and then select the minimum error. Thanks for your help!